# MBP 16" 2019 Ventura Permission Issue

Tags: mail.app, permission, keynote, ventura

I've been having a series of permissions related issues with my 2019 16" MBP running Ventura 13.5.1
I can't actually remember if the problem starts before or after upgrading to Ventura.

**Keynote**

Opening and editing keynote files just stopped working altogether, I cannot insert images (any image) with error message "the image xxxxx.jpg cannot be inserted". At first i can resolve the issue by quitting and reopening Keynote and said file. but then it also prevents me from saving the document & saving as the document. It gives error message "The document “SS_Credentials_221214 copy” could not be saved as “xxxx copy.key”. You don’t have permission." "To view or change permissions, select the item in the Finder and choose File > Get Info."

**Preview and Quicklook**

Preview kinda does the same thing, it opens one file, and when i try to open another file (pdf, jpeg, whatever) just give me an error message saying i dont have permissions to open said file.

Quicklook works sometimes / inconsistently, say I have a folder of images, when i click on the spacebar, it sometimes shows the big preview, and as i go down the list of images, sometimes it just shows the small icons with filename on the right of it.

**Mail**

Apple mail is the latest 'symptom' that I discovered. I cannot seem to attach files while composing anymore, the attached file will turn up as corrupted on the receiving end.

When i drag a file / attach using the icon and then select through finder window, the file attaches and shows the size. but then when i try to preview by hitting the spacebar, gets an error messsage saying "Mail was unable to save the attachment “xxxxx.pdf” to disk. Verify that your downloads folder exists and is writable."

**Solutions I've Tried**

I've tried repairing permission with disk utility, as well as repairing via safemode & recovery mode.

Lastly i've tried reinstalling macOS as well, but the problem still persists.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Comment: Where are you saving/opening these files from? What are the permissions on them? (use Get Info to show the permissions - or Terminal if you know how.) Repairing Permissions with Disk Utility hasn't been a thing for several years (and it's abilities were grossly over-stated.) There is a method to reset user account permissions in Recovery mode -- is that what you did?

Comment: The files are random, from all over finder: desktop, downloads, documents, etc. I have read and write permissions for all of those files (from get info).

"There is a method to reset user account permissions in Recovery mode -- is that what you did?" can you link me to an article on how to do this?

Comment: ok, i just googled how to and did that, problem still seems to exist.

Also worth noting, i use dropbox and have it installed on my computer. from what i read, dropbox and google drive can sometimes mess w the files & permissions.

Comment: Are these files synced by Dropbox and Google at the same time? Yes, that might well cause problems. But if the files are just in folders on your user account that aren't synced, I wouldn't expect a problem. Have you modified your user account, or migrated these files from another Mac? It would be useful to see a screenshot or text of the complete set of three permissions, and the values they have.

Comment: it's not, just dropbox, but sometimes even the local files in desktop / downloads is having that issue. here's a [screenshot](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/trkpruz4g7nwa9qs2sr95/Screenshot-2023-08-23-at-10.24.55-AM.png?rlkey=hoqehdqo2kwdd5w1dpidrrez0&dl=0) of one of the file i'm having issue with. Cannot open in preview, but if i quit preview and double click the file, it opens.